# How to return a list of entities that are not in a given list

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

In `NHibernate`, how can I return a list of entities that are not in a given list?

Let's say I have a `Client` entity and I have a list defined called `IList<Client> notInClients`. I know that I want my sql to turn out something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Clients c1
WHERE c1.ClientId NOT IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM Clients c2
    WHERE c2.ClientId IN ('1', '2', '3', '4')
)
```

I'm assuming I would need to use a `DetachedCriteria` for this. Maybe something like:

```
var clients = session.CreateCriteria("c1")
    .Add(
        Subqueries.PropertyNotIn("c1.ClientId",
            DetachedCriteria.For<Client>("c2").HOW_DO_I_ADD_MY_LIST)));
```

I guess I'm just not sure how to build my subquery. Am I going down the right path on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
var notGuids = from c in notClients
               select c.ClientId;

var clients = unitOfWork.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Client))
    .Add(Expression.Not(Expression.In("ClientId", notGuids.ToArray()))).List<Client>();
```